[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found
I currently have a late 2011 MacBook Pro, but I've done a few modifications...she now has 2 TB SSD installed internally, along with 16GB of RAM. The OS has been upgraded to Catalina 10.15.7. Im currently working with Python 3.7 via an anaconda3 setup with Jupyter Notebook. I'm convinced it is not an access/firewall issue b/c I can connect to the Azure SQL database via a VM and SQL Server, as well as through VS Code2 or PyCharm 2024.
I need to modify my current Python script to access the Azure SQL db, which I've done but I'm having a devil of a time connecting successfully!
I've attached screen shots of my terminal to show the odbcinst.ini file can be read/queried and return the correct configuration which I've managed to update based on the countless resources and similar questions asked. The /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib file pyodbc is looking for has a symlink and is shown on the last few lines of my terminal screenshot. This is the same path used to update the server name in the odbcinst.ini file.  I've even provided screen shots of my .zshrc profile where I've explicitly defined the paths for "PATH" and "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" based on suggestion provided via StackOverflow. Again, unfortunately nothing has worked.
Please help.








Can't open lib '/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found doesn't necessarily mean that that exact file cannot be found, i.e.: it could also be one of that file's dependencies. Does ldd /usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib mention any missing files?

Aside... Homebrew isn't supported on macOS Catalina 10.15 any more. You will be receiving numerous "unsupported" warnings whenever you do a brew update or brew install.

Check this document  to install the driver. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos?view=sql-server-ver16

;' pyodbc.Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/user/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")


If  ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server  is not installed properly, then you may get the above error. Follow the MS Document  to install the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (macOS). Along with that, use the code below to connect to the SQL Server using  pyodbc:
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                       '<serverName>;'
                       'DATABASE=<databaseName>;'
                       'UID=<userName>;'
                       'PWD=<password>')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM <tableName>")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print(row)


It will connect successfully, as shown below:

For more information, you can refer to  this.
